# How to use getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent method in WallpaperManager?

Tags: java, android, crop, android-4.4-kitkat, wallpaper

I want to know how to use `getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent` method in the WallpaperMannager class

I'm using it this way:

```
getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri.fromFile(new File(wallpaper_path)));
```

But that throws the exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image URI must be of the content scheme type
```

How can I correct this?